# PHP: How to save multiple checkbox array from $_POST in variable

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I am new to PHP and am looking for some help with the following:

I have a large HTML form with various inputs, selects and textareas. On submit I **pass all field values to another PHP page** to create an email with them.

**This works** as intended for text inputs, radio buttons, selects, textareas etc. **but not for checkboxes**.

In the form I have multiple checkboxes that all look as follows using the same name:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language1' name='language[]' value='de - German' />
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language2' name='language[]' value='en - English' />
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language3' name='language[]' value='fr - French' />
<!-- ... -->
```

On the PHP side I tried the following but if I then use `$languages` for my email body it shows as blank (while all other fields appear correctly):

```
$languages = implode(',', $_POST['language[]']);
```

What I am trying to do is to save all values from the `$_POST["language"]` array in one variable, separated with commas (and no comma at the end).

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try `$_POST['language']` in place of `$_POST['language[]']` ?

Comment: This worked great - see below. Thanks again - I voted you up as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `anyname[]` in the form, PHP will translate it to an array, but without the `[]` in the name. So this should work:

```
$languages = implode(',', $_POST['language']);
```

Note that unchecked checkboxes are not posted, so if you check none, no value is posted and `$_POST['language']` will not be set. You would have to check for that.

```
$languages = 'No languages selected';
if (isset($_POST['language'])){
  $languages = implode(',', $_POST['language']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - let me try this out.

Comment: Awesome - this works great. Life can be so easy sometimes. :) Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks for the update as well. One question on this: It should be rare that no checkbox will be checked here (since one of them is checked by default). Can it cause any issues if I don't check if any value was posted for this, i.e. do I have to do this ?

Comment: Yes. If you just read `$_POST['language']` if it doesn't exist, it will cause a run-time error and your script will end prematurely. You *think* it should be rare, but it's just user input. One could easily press a button without first checking a box, and if you think it should almost never happen, it will probably happen after five minutes. ;) I can tell from experience. :p

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language1' name='language[]' value='1' />
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language2' name='language[]' value='2' />
<input type='checkbox' class='someClass' id='language3' name='language[]' value='3' />
<!-- ... -->
```

PHP

```
$language_ = array(1=>'de - German',2=>'en - English',3=>'fr - French');
if (!empty($_GET['language'])) {
     foreach ($_GET['language'] as $l) {
                $lan0 .= $language_[$l].', ';
            }
echo rtrim($lan0,", ");
```